# How to check total files size in hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to calculate the total file size of HDFS file directory in GB or MB? I dont want to use du command. Without that is there a way

Directory - /test/my_dir

Answer (score 1):

you  can  use `df`  or  `report`  、`'hadoop fs -count -q -h` it will show  the  total size

```
[root@hadoop0 ~]# hadoop fs -df -h /
Filesystem              Size    Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://hadoop0:8020  119.9 G  27.8 G     62.3 G   23%


[root@hadoop0 ~]# hadoop dfsadmin -report 
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 128770375680 (119.93 GB)
Present Capacity: 96752292952 (90.11 GB)
DFS Remaining: 66886767274 (62.29 GB)
DFS Used: 29865525678 (27.81 GB)
DFS Used%: 30.87%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```

Comment: I shouldnt use df/du command. Appart from that is there a way to do from ls command

Comment: Hi As i said earlier. I dont want to use df/du or any admin related commands which is disabled for me. Hence is there any other way using hadoop fs -ls and combination of awk

Comment: @user2672739  what  about  ''hadoop fs -count -q  -h  ''    in  hadoop   if  you   use ''ls -h '  to show  its size   when the  file directory is too large, the size of  directory will be  0. that is a big problem